# Sending an email to a list of people from a query - Problem with loop

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that shows the results of an union query that has a button with the following code. What I want the button to do is email each person on that query separately with their information.  If I leave the Do Until - Loop off it creates the email perfectly. When I include the loop I get an odd message,

Run-Time error '-1834742 (ffe4010a)':
The item has been moved or deleted focused on the .bodyformat line below. I tried commenting out that line to see what happened, and the error moved to the .to line. I've looked over my Do Until Loop and checked the Microsoft page as well as a google search for that ridiculous run time error, but I'm striking out.  Does anyone see what I'm missing?

`````
Private Sub btnSend_Click()
Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strPDHSUM As String
Dim sqls As String
Dim MyDb As DAO.Database
Dim rsEmail As DAO.Recordset
    Set MyDb = CurrentDb
    Set rsEmail = MyDb.OpenRecordset("eqREPPDHSummaryZero")
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With rsEmail
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until rsEmail.EOF
    strEmail = .Fields(2)
    strPDHSUM = .Fields(1)
        With MailOutLook
            .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
            .To = strEmail
            '.CC = ""
            '.bcc = ""
            .Subject = "PDH Summary"
            .HTMLBody = "Hello!" & "<br>" & "This is an automated reminder about the Professional Development Hour requirement for PFS. Each PFS staff member is required to have 4 hours of approved professional development each year. " & "<br>" & "<br>" & "So far this year you have taken " & strPDHSUM & " PD hours." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Additional PDH classes are held each month and can be found at the " & "<a href=https://avalidaddress.com>PDH Class Schedule on OnBase</a> " & "If you feel there is an error in this information or need assistance signing up for PDH credits, please email " & "<a href=mailto:MyEmail@whereIWork.edu>Rob Loughrey</a>." & "<Br>" & "<br>" & "Thank you," & "<br>" & "PFS Education and Quality Unit"
            .Send
            '.Display    'Used during testing without sending (Comment out .Send if using this line)
        End With
        sqls = "INSERT INTO tblEmails " _
            & "(TypeofEmail, SendDateTime, EmailAddress) VALUES " _
            & "('PDH Summary', Now(), '" & strEmail & "');"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sqls

    .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
Set MyDb = Nothing
Set rsEmail = Nothing
End Sub````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:
`Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)` into recordset loop

```
Do Until rsEmail.EOF
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

Have to create as many mail items as emails sending. When it was outside For loop, just created one mail item which only worked with first mail sent, when loop was hit a second time MailOutlook was gone so code failed.